# How to pause Resque processing on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, resque, resque-scheduler

I'm migrating from Delayed_jobs to Resque and given that I'm going to have a lot of jobs always queued (some in the future), it's impossible to know when I can scale workers down to 0 to do a safe new release.

Is there any way to safely tell workers on Heroku to finish processing the current job but not take any new one?

That way , I can scale workers down to zero to do a safe release of a new version on Heroku when jobs are not processing anything.

Then I can scale back up number of workers and resume processing.

Comment: you can prioritize the jobs `QUEUES=critical,qeued, new_job rake resque:work` instead of stop new

Answer (score 1):

Resque workers respond to a few different signals:

```
QUIT - Wait for child to finish processing then exit
TERM / INT - Immediately kill child then exit
USR1 - Immediately kill child but don't exit
**USR2 - Don't start to process any new jobs**
CONT - Start to process new jobs again after a USR2
```

In your case you want to not process new jobs so you can use `USR2`

More read on the signal in heroku

http://hone.herokuapp.com/resque/2012/08/21/resque-signals.html

You need to know the process id and send the signal

```
USR2 rscue.pid
```

Comment: Sounds good, how do you send USR2 signal to all your workers on Heroku?

Comment: Unless I missed something, this doesn't explain how to **send** a signal to all Heroku workers.

Comment: I need to run this on Heroku, not locally